# tableView crashes when adding the first item (and also when deleting last item)

Tags: ios, tableview

After cleaning up my code and making it ready for deployment I encountered a weird problem. When I try to add a contact to my tableview it always crashes when the empty is array. After that its not problem to add as many as you want. And also when I delete a contact and the array is empty, it also crashes with the same error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   ' -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Here is what I do: I add a contact via php to my database, read it out with xml and give it back to the app so the user can instantly see what happened (adding a contact that is). There is a lot of code involved so I stick to the basics for now.
When the view loads the array gets allocated. User can add a contact. While adding the contact a php file is called that creates the xml file where the contacts are saved.

Here is where I get the object back and paste it into my array and display it

```
self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.tabelle count]];

self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *fileName = [prefs stringForKey:@"number"];
NSString *cc = [prefs stringForKey:@"Code"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://myserver/%@%@.xml", cc, fileName];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

DataFileToObjectParser *myParser = [[DataFileToObjectParser alloc] parseXMLAtUrl:url toObject:@"contacts" parseError:nil];

for(int i = 0; i < [[myParser items] count]; i++) {
    contacts *new = [[Telefonbuch alloc] init];
    new = (contacts *) [[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i];
    [numbers addObject:new];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

And here is how it gets displayed, nothing special:

```
NSString *TableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] fname]]; 
NSString *TableText2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lname]];    
NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", TableText, TableText2];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

Comment: First off, you should probably not name a variable `new`, as that's a keyword in Objective-C++ and a class method name in Objective-C. Secondly, you can see exactly where in the code the problem is by telling the debugger to break on Objective-C exceptions. As soon as it detects the exception, the debugger will stop and show you the stack trace that lead to the problem.

Comment: I think also, that you may be loading the data too late. Your table view may be asking for data from the array before it is correctly set up.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @Abizern that is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop sounds strange.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [[myParser items] count]; i++) {
    contacts *new = [[Telefonbuch alloc] init];
    new = (contacts *) [[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i];
    [numbers addObject:new];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

First avoid to use `new` keyword (as user1118321 already suggested).

Then, what is `contacts`? Is `contacts` a superclass of type `Telefonbuch`?

What do these two lines mean?

```
contacts *new = [[Telefonbuch alloc] init];
new = (contacts *) [[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i];
```

You alloc-init an instance of `Telefonbuch` class to a `new` (avoid this) variable but then you assign that variable to another object. Why?

The right code could be like the following.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [[myParser items] count]; i++) {
   Telefonbuch* newContact = (Telefonbuch*) [[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i]; // or contacts* newContact = (contacts*) [[myParser items] objectAtIndex:i];
   // maybe it could be better to rename contacts with a capital letter
   [numbers addObject:newContact];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

**Some notes**

If you want to add or delete item to a table view, you need to do it in 2 stages:

1) Deal with your model

```
[yourModel removeObjectAtIndex:row];
```

2) Deal with your table’s animation

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

If you need to download content, maybe you could consider to do it asynchrously without blocking the main thread. In particular, this is could be the synchronous call that could be a blocking one (since I don't have any details I'm only supposing it).

```
DataFileToObjectParser *myParser = [[DataFileToObjectParser alloc] parseXMLAtUrl:url toObject:@"contacts" parseError:nil];
```

If you don't use ARC, **pay attention to memory management**.

Hope it helps.